issue in Django 5.0.2 and django_rest_framework
hi guys i have issue with reading sql data from postgresql with django.
i created my model with manage.py inspectdb
command from existing database.
my model:
from django.db import models

class Regions(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=4)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "regions"

My serializer:
from rest_framework import serializers


class RegionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = "france.models.Regions"
        fields = "__all__"



my viewset:
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Regions
from .serializers import RegionsSerializer


class RegionsView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        regions = Regions.objects.all()
        serializer = RegionsSerializer(regions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

and error i get:
AttributeError at /regions/
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:1000/regions/
Django Version: 5.0.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location: C:\Projects\play_ground\python\django_one\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\model_meta.py, line 35, in get_field_info
Raised during:  france.views.RegionsView
Python Executable:  C:\Projects\play_ground\python\django_one\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.12.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Projects\\play_ground\\python\\django_one',
 'C:\\Users\\safkh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\safkh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\safkh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\safkh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312',
 'C:\\Projects\\play_ground\\python\\django_one\\venv',
 'C:\\Projects\\play_ground\\python\\django_one\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 05 Apr 2024 08:19:46 +0000

can you help me with issue thnx all

The serializer Meta can not work with a string as model, but should refer to the model class, so:
from france.models import Regions
from rest_framework import serializers


class RegionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Regions
        fields = '__all__'


Note: normally a Django model is given a singular name, so Region instead of Regions.


The error is in the class meta in your "Regions" model , here is the correct approach
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Regions

class RegionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Regions
       fields = "__all__"

